# Simple Image Upload from Unity to Firebase not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I am working on an IOS App which I create with Unity in C# (Unity 2018.2.5f1). Now I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage to get familiar with it. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

I assume there is a problem with the path to the local file. I get the following error in XCode when running the app.

Firebase.Storage.Storage.StorageException: There is no object at the desired reference.

The file swift.jpg definitively exists on the iPhone.

Your help is very welcome.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Upload : MonoBehaviour {

    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storage_ref;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://[My Storage URL]");

        // File located on disk
        string local_file = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "swift.jpg";

        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        StorageReference image_ref = storage_ref.Child("images/swift.jpeg");

        // Upload the file to the path
        image_ref.PutFileAsync(local_file)
          .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
              if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
                  Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
              }
              else {
                  // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                  // StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                  // string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                  // Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                  // Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);
              }
          });
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Debug in XCode
...
 
(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)

2019-01-06 21:59:55.922265+0100 arnav[6835:1687542] CFURLResourceIsReachable failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme
2019-01-06 21:59:55.979115+0100 arnav[6835:1687542] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-01-06 21:59:55.979858+0100 arnav[6835:1687542] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
Upload Cancled
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
string local_file = "file:///" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "swift.jpg";
```

Or

```
string local_file = "file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "swift.jpg";
```

Or

```
string local_file = "file:\\" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "swift.jpg";
```

Hope one of these will work.

Comment: "file:///" fixed it for me on iOS where the issue arose. The error didn't happen when running in the Editor. Adding the protocol appears to work in Editor as well as building to iOS.

Comment: For me it was "file://" . Thanks!